# How to execute JQuery BEFORE Safari submits form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, safari

I've run into an issue that only seems to a problem in Safari. I have an overlay that is set to `display:none` in it's css. When the user clicks submit I want the overlay to show until processing is finished. I did this initially by just binding this to the button's `on('click'...` function in jquery. This worked just fine except in Safari. Safari wants to execute the submit before the calls in the click. So, based on some other things I found I instead put this all on the submit event for the form instead of the click and used a timeout object set to 0. Like this:

```
$('#tcmi-shop-cart-checkout').submit(function(){
    var showOverlay = function(){$('#processing-overlay').css('display','block')};
     setTimeout(showOverlay,0);
});
```

This, again, works in all other browsers except Safari. Safari still wants to submit the form data and wait for a response before it executes this. How can I make Safari show this overlay BEFORE submitting the data?

Comment: I'm not sure whatever it will work or not, but you should try preventDefault onsubmit of form, do your tasks, and manually submit it.

Comment: Can post `html` , `css` ?

Comment: the html is dynamically generated because it comes from a custom drupal form I've written using their Form API for custom modules.

Comment: @LoneWolfPR See post.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried preventDefault()?

If you're just POSTing some data via the form, you could do something like this (in pseudocode):

```
#form.submit() {
  preventDefault()
  setOverlay(true)
  POST()
    .then(setOverlay(false))
}
```

Basically, you want to prevent the default form submit, display the overlay right after, and then submit the form data using ajax. You have access to the callback function when its finished, and its there you can turn the overlay off.

Comment: This causes a different problem I mention in the proposed solution above.

Comment: @LoneWolfPR , please clarify your question and add all necessary informations in order to get a proper answer

Comment: I'm not sure what needs clarifying. I thought I had added all necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the button is a "submit" button and the submit event fired by clicking it is firing before your javascript has a chance to show the overlay. Try submitting the form with javascript instead and use `preventDefault` to eat the submit event from the button, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#submitButton').click(function(e) {
        $('#processing-overlay').css('display', 'block');
        $('#tcmi-shop-cart-checkout').submit();
        e.preventDefault();
    });             
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is problematic too. This is a multi-step form using drupal's Form API. When I do this, instead of moving on it actually takes me back for some reason. That's not to say I couldn't fix that somehow. I was just hoping for a way to work around Safari's issue without having to rework a lot of other code.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with that form API but perhaps `preventDefault` would be more effective than returning false?  That is probably a better solution than returning false anyway.  I've updated the solution, give that a shot.

Comment: @LoneWolfPR please clarify your question and add all necessary informations in order to get a proper answer

Comment: I'm not sure what needs clarifying. I thought I had provided all necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#tcmi-shop-cart-checkout").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
    var el = $(this), elem = $("#processing-overlay");
    var settings = {};
    settings.url = el.attr("action");
    settings.type = el.attr("method");
    settings.context = elem;
    settings.data = el.serialize();

   elem.toggle(function() {
       $.ajax(settings)
       .then(function success(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
         console.log(data);
         $(this).toggle()
       }, function error(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
       })
    })
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bmLkauzp/

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue and I solve it with:

```
$(document).on("click", "input[type=\"submit\"]", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this).closest("form"),

    // Do whatever you want

    setTimeout(function () {
        $form.unbind('submit').submit();
    }, 200);
});
```

You can add additional check for safari browser if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the setTimeout and it should work fine.
When calling setTimeout you are pushing the function to the event-queue and releasing the thread and the form submit is happening at that time.

In code:

```
$('#tcmi-shop-cart-checkout').submit(function(){
    $('#processing-overlay').css('display','block');
});
```

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work. The problem is Safari, for some reason, processes it's events differently than every other browser and wants to handle the submit before everything else. The setTimeout was a hack some people had said worked. It didn't. Unfortunately, neither did your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up having to do a crazy hack to make this work. It's basically a combination of preventDefault() as mentioned above with some other stuff. Because it's a Drupal form if I do form.submit() it would use the 'back' button i have on my form instead of the actual submit causing an obvious problem. So I had to use the actual submit button to do the trigger. This involved basically triggering a second call on the button. The first time shows the overlay then calls the submit again and actually triggers the submit. Here's the code:

```
        var submitOpen = true;
        $('#edit-submit-order').on('click',function(e){
          if (submitOpen) {
               e.preventDefault();
               $('#processing-overlay').css('display','block');
               submitOpen = false;
               setTimeout(function(){$('#edit-submit-order').trigger('click')},5);
          } else {
               submitOpen = true
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. It's not "clean" but it works :)

```
var someForm = $('.someform');
var someOverlay = $('.someOverlay');

someForm.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    someForm.off('submit');
    someOverlay.fadeIn('fast', function(){
        someForm.submit();
    });
});
```